# Why multiple mail are sent in Handling Error Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, email, laravel

In the `global.php` file, I want to send me an email if an error occured.

So I do this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Mail::send('error.mail', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->from('info@example.com', 'Error');
        $message->to('me@example.com', 'Me')
                ->subject('Error');
    });

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

But it sends me a random number of the same mail each times instead of once.
This is for my local. I didn't test in production yet.

I precise that in my log file, the error is reported only once.

What did I miss ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have more than one error

Comment: Obviously I check for that suggestion before, but no, it's always the same message error same file same line

Comment: this library might be helpful http://dineshrabara.github.io/bugonemail/

Comment: Good suggestion thank you, I should use that.
But I would know why the same mail is send several times..

Comment: Try adding microtime to the email or logging to the file. As mentioned you probably have more errors. Might be the same file, same line, multiple times.

Comment: Yes but why the number of email changes each time I refresh with the same error ? This is why I don't understand if there is more than one error the number of email sent should be the same each times

Comment: Logging will return true on success, so you could try `if(Log::error($exception) { // Send email }`. That way it should only send an email when the error has been logged.

Comment: I try but it still the same..